# How do I loop a background task in discord.py and why does my code not work?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How can I send a message every x time with a discord bot with discord.py?

Here is my code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks
import os

TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'



bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',help_command=None,activity=discord.Game(name="!help"))


@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def ping(channel):
    
    print("is the function being called")
    
    channel = bot.get_channel(877115461014282320)
    
    await channel.send('embed=embed')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Edit: I know I shouldn't leak my key but I edited it after 10 seconds and removed a letter why could someone still access it?

Comment: Does your current code not work? If so, what is it doing that is not correct, and what is the expected outcome?

Comment: you have to run `ping.start()` - ie. in `on_ready()` or in some `command`

Answer (score 3):

You have to start task using `ping.start()` in event `on_ready` or in some `command`.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks
import os

TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', help_command=None, activity=discord.Game(name="!help"))

@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def ping():
    print("is the function being called")
    #channel = bot.get_channel(877115461014282320)
    #await channel.send('embed=embed')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('on ready')
    ping.start()

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

---

You have also `ping.stop()`, `ping.cancel()`, etc. See doc: [tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html)